# If active record object has attribute and is unique

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to add a callback to a rails model that checks if the attribute exits and then checks if it is unique.

The attribute is a token that maybe shared either across lots of active record objects, for a single object, or can be nil.

For each of these tokens I would like to carry out an action only once and not for each of the active record objects that have the token.

for example:

I create a new record with the token:

```
thing.create(token = "abc")
```

This would be the first time an object has been created with the token "abc". so I would take action (in this case start a sidekiq worker)

Next I add a second record with the same token:

```
thing.create(token = "abc")
```

This would be the second time this token is used so I would not take action.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `after_commit`:

```
after_commit :do_foo, on: :create

private

def do_foo
  return if Model.exists?(token: token)

  do_what_you_have_to_do
end
```

The method checks if there's already a record with the same token, if so it returns from the method itself. Otherwise you can proceed to do what you need.